# trying to call a function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

what is wrong with my script? I am trying to call a function to see if a file is larger than a specified amount. If it is, i would like to remove the second file. If it is not larger than the specified amount than i would like the program to exit. Instead, I get this error message:
"syntax error near unexpected token `FILE'"
Can someone please help or direct me where I can get some help? Thanks. I have a Bash shell.

```
function e{
FILE = $1
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILE") 
if [ "$FILESIZE" -gt 2048 ]; then
   echo "File $1 exists"
   `rm $2`
else
   echo "File $1 does not exist" 
   exit 
fi
}

e AD4_1hit.paired_mult.bam AD4_1hit.halfmapping_transloc.bam
```

Comment: Why would you assume the file does not exist if FILESIZE <= 2048?  That will certainly confuse the user.

Comment: @WilliamPursell he must be a dailywtf reader.

Comment: need a space between `e` and `{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces around the `=` ...

```
FILE=$1
```

BTW, you don't need the command-substitution `...` syntax around your `rm` command.

```
e () {
  FILE=$1
  FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILE")
  if [ "$FILESIZE" -gt 2048 ]; then
     echo "File $1 exists"
     rm $2
  else
     echo "File $1 does not exist"
     exit
  fi
}
```